# Rights of remand prisoner in India to visit ailing sick mother

Tags: criminal-law, india, human-rights, indian-penal-code

A remand prisoner in India having criminal cases in multiple states.
In remand for over 8 years.
The prisoner's mother is very sick with various health issues and wanted to spend few days with mother on escort visit for few days.

Question 1: remand prisoner having cases in multiple states. Can the remand prisoner move the HIGH court of ANOTHER state where is NOT lodged in the judicial custody but has an ongoing case. Does the HIGH court of other state in this given situation has the right to grant escort visit or leave to visit sick mother. Please note: the lower court earlier has granted such visits in the past for this remand prisoner, however now the new judge in the lower court is not granting such requests, hence this question on particularly on high court.

Question 2: is there any provision in the Indian law for granting such leave for the remand prisoner to visit sick mother. Please list the appropriate sections of CrPC India, with valuable advice on this matter how to take this forward.
Valuable citations if any by the supreme court.
Many thanks